# cut text in table with PHP or jQuery/html/css

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<table id="tab">
    <tr><td>....</td><td>2222</td></tr>
    <tr><td>@@@@</td><td>4444</td></tr>
</table>

#tab td {
   border: solid 1px red;
   max-width: 50px;
}
```

**LIVE EXAMPLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/mCxqD/

i would like cut text in TD if he is too long. I can use strlen and substr, but:

strlen(....) = 4;
strlen(@@@@) = 4;

and in table occupy different amount of space.

How is the best way for this? I don't have wrap to new line. 
I would like somethings: http://jsfiddle.net/mCxqD/1/

**edit:**
overflow:hidden is good, but what if i would like add for overflow text for example "*"?
http://jsfiddle.net/7ksD7/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little round-about (and using jQuery... although you could do this with regular JS easily enough), but you could try using JS to wrap the text in a span tag and measure it while comparing against the max width. You might need to tweak a few things (e.g. - make sure that you compensate for the width of the character used to denote a cut-off), but I think this should work (if you don't have text-overflow available):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('td').each(function() {
        var contents = $(this).html();
        var max_width = $(this).css('max-width').replace('px', '');
        var cut_char = '*';

        $(this).html('');
        $(this).append('<span>' + contents + '</span>');
        var $span = $(this).find('span:first');

        var content_width = $span.innerWidth();

        while (content_width > max_width) {
            var str = $span.html();
            $span.html(str.substring(0, str.length - 1));

            content_width = $span.innerWidth();

            if (content_width < max_width) {
                $span.html(str.substring(0, str.length - 2) + cut_char);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Here's your fiddle updated:
http://jsfiddle.net/mCxqD/6/

Answer (score 3):

Add `overflow: hidden`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7ksD7/

Comment: +1, thanks, but what if i would like add for overflow text for example "8"?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Could you give an example?

Comment: As @VinayC answered, `text-overflow: ellipsis` will add `...` to the clipped text. Doesn't work in Firefox earlier than 7, though. I don't think there's a CSS way to display other characters than the ellipsis.

Comment: overflow only hide the text after the width limit, no. of characters which best fit in the limit should appear.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet would be text-overflow property -

```
#tab td {
   border: solid 1px red;
   max-width: 50px;
   overflow:hidden;
   white-space:nowrap;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/7ksD7/5/

See [more here](http://deepubalan.com/blog/2010/11/27/text-overflow-css3-property-explained-pure-css-solution-to-get-ellipsis/) about the same - although this article says that the property is not supported on FF, at least my browser (FF 7) appears to support it.